# Flutter jsonDecode returns String instead of List

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I want to decode my json to a List but `jsonDecode` returns String instead of List.

My JSON:

```
[{
    "TicketID": 31,
    "EmpID": "11553",
    "Name": "Test",
    "Location": null,
    "PhoneExt": 345345,
    "Code": null,
    "Reason": null,
    "Category": null,
    "Created": null,
    "Username": "abc",
    "OtherLocation": null,
    "Room": null,
    "Floor": null,
    "CodeBlueDone": null,
    "CodeBlueDoneDate": null,
    "LocationCode": null,
    "PatientType": null,
    "EmergencyType": "Emergency",
    "FilledDateTime": null,
    "SubmitDateTime": null,
    "Type": null,
    "CallTime": "2022-08-26T13:43:25.003",
    "Status": "New"
}, {
    "TicketID": 30,
    "EmpID": "12",
    "Name": "dbdb",
    "Location": null,
    "PhoneExt": 123,
    "Code": null,
    "Reason": null,
    "Category": null,
    "Created": null,
    "Username": "abc",
    "OtherLocation": null,
    "Room": null,
    "Floor": null,
    "CodeBlueDone": null,
    "CodeBlueDoneDate": null,
    "LocationCode": null,
    "PatientType": null,
    "EmergencyType": "Emergency",
    "FilledDateTime": null,
    "SubmitDateTime": null,
    "Type": null,
    "CallTime": "2022-08-25T21:14:39.807",
    "Status": "New"
}]
```

```dart
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  jsonDecode(response.body);
  print(jsonDecode(response.body).runtimeType);
}
```

```dart
Future<List> _getDataFromWeb() async {
  try {
    await http.post(
      Uri.parse(apiURL),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      },
    ).then((response) {
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        try {
          final resp = jsonDecode(response.body) as List?;
          print(resp.runtimeType);
        } catch (ex) {
          print("_getDataFromWeb() error: ${ex}");
        }
      } else if (response.statusCode == 404) {
        print("Error 404: ${response.statusCode}");
      } else {
        print("Error: ${response.statusCode}");
      }
    }).catchError((error) {
      print("Error: " + error);
    });
  } catch (ex) {
    print("API-ERR: $ex");
  }
}
```

Full code to decode is given above

Why the flutter jsonDecode or json.Decode doesn't return a List from above JSON?

**EDIT**

Calling jsonDecode two times works and returns List

```dart
final resp = jsonDecode(jsonDecode(response.body));
print(resp.runtimeType);
```

I wonder why calling jsonDecode() two times is needed?

Comment: Can you include how you are parsing the response

Comment: I am trying to first decode the json like ```jsonDecode(response.body)```

Comment: can you include that part

Comment: ```if (response.statusCode == 200) {jsonDecode(response.body);print(jsonDecode(response.body).runtimeType);}``` the runtimeType returns String whereas it should return List

Comment: full snippet up to list parser

Comment: I am not parsing it yet, the jsonDecode has to return a List first

Comment: Is the json is full structured on question?

Comment: the json you put here is the exact print result?

Comment: yes json is full as on question, its the exact print

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling jsonDecode two times works and returns List

```dart
final resp = jsonDecode(jsonDecode(response.body));
print(resp.runtimeType);
```

Finally found the answer after investing hours into it.

Comment: This is the solution, I do not know why the result of the conversion remains a string, But passing the result of the decoded json to the outter decode function returns a valid json data.

Comment: Can confirm it's still an issue, and this is the fix.

Comment: I had to also do jsonDecode(jsonDecode(...  to properly decode a json array of objects.  Kept getting the message:

`Expected a value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>', but got one of type 'String'`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
json.decode(response.body) as List;
```

**EDIT**

Try this format

```dart
Future<List> _getDataFromWeb() async {
  try {
    var response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(apiURL),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      },
    );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        try {
          final resp = json.decode(response.body.toString()) as List?;
          print(resp.runtimeType);
        } catch (ex) {
          print("_getDataFromWeb() error: ${ex}");
        }
      } else if (response.statusCode == 404) {
        print("Error 404: ${response.statusCode}");
      } else {
        print("Error: ${response.statusCode}");
      }
    }
  } catch (ex) {
    print("API-ERR: $ex");
  }
}
```

Comment: .toList() is not a function of jsonDecode() or json.decode()

Comment: Sorry my bad. Edited my answer

Comment: It throws this error: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast

Comment: You probably created a method of json by mistake. If you hover on json.decodes's `json` do you see `dart:convert` ?

Comment: Yes i do see ```dart:convert```

Comment: can you post the full code here please? Not sure what's going wrong

Comment: Question updated to show full code

Comment: instead of  final resp = jsonDecode(response.body) as List?; try `final Response = json.decode(response.body) as List?`

Comment: tried both jsonDecode() and json.decode() but same result

Comment: Same error: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>?' in type cast

Comment: Can you add the full class code here/? I think you added some method by mistake

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```dart
 final response = jsonDecode(response.body) as List?;
 print(response.runtimeType);
```

Comment: It throws error:  type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>?' in type cast

Comment: I think there is some issue that isn't included on question. print the `response` and how you are handling it

Comment: Updated question to show how I am trying to decode json

Comment: Can you try again by printing `response`

Comment: print(response);   ----->  Instance of 'Response'

Comment: try `response.toString()` if fails `response.body`

Comment: which response object you are talking about, the response returned by API ?

Comment: Yes the api response raw data, you can use postman to it

Comment: Postman or VS Code extension Thunder prints the exact json as posted in question. However when i print raw response.body in flutter it shows like this: ```"[{\"TicketID\":31,\"EmpID\":\"11553\",``` until the end of json

Comment: try remove `await`

Comment: No luck, same error: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>?' in type cast

Comment: try `jsonDecode(response) as List?` then `response as List?`, then `response.body as List?` I am certain question is missing something or like saving the file or others stuff

Comment: I updated my question, calling jsonDecode() two times returns a List, wonder why calling two times works

Comment: Maybe encoded two times 

Comment: No, its encoded once only, its strange

Comment: Sorry dont know .

Answer (score 0):

Try this code via [QuickType](https://app.quicktype.io/)

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final model = modelFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

List<Model> modelFromJson(String str) => List<Model>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Model.fromJson(x)));

String modelToJson(List<Model> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Model {
    Model({
        this.ticketId,
        this.empId,
        this.name,
        this.location,
        this.phoneExt,
        this.code,
        this.reason,
        this.category,
        this.created,
        this.username,
        this.otherLocation,
        this.room,
        this.floor,
        this.codeBlueDone,
        this.codeBlueDoneDate,
        this.locationCode,
        this.patientType,
        this.emergencyType,
        this.filledDateTime,
        this.submitDateTime,
        this.type,
        this.callTime,
        this.status,
    });

    int ticketId;
    String empId;
    String name;
    dynamic location;
    int phoneExt;
    dynamic code;
    dynamic reason;
    dynamic category;
    dynamic created;
    String username;
    dynamic otherLocation;
    dynamic room;
    dynamic floor;
    dynamic codeBlueDone;
    dynamic codeBlueDoneDate;
    dynamic locationCode;
    dynamic patientType;
    String emergencyType;
    dynamic filledDateTime;
    dynamic submitDateTime;
    dynamic type;
    DateTime callTime;
    String status;

    factory Model.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Model(
        ticketId: json["TicketID"],
        empId: json["EmpID"],
        name: json["Name"],
        location: json["Location"],
        phoneExt: json["PhoneExt"],
        code: json["Code"],
        reason: json["Reason"],
        category: json["Category"],
        created: json["Created"],
        username: json["Username"],
        otherLocation: json["OtherLocation"],
        room: json["Room"],
        floor: json["Floor"],
        codeBlueDone: json["CodeBlueDone"],
        codeBlueDoneDate: json["CodeBlueDoneDate"],
        locationCode: json["LocationCode"],
        patientType: json["PatientType"],
        emergencyType: json["EmergencyType"],
        filledDateTime: json["FilledDateTime"],
        submitDateTime: json["SubmitDateTime"],
        type: json["Type"],
        callTime: DateTime.parse(json["CallTime"]),
        status: json["Status"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "TicketID": ticketId,
        "EmpID": empId,
        "Name": name,
        "Location": location,
        "PhoneExt": phoneExt,
        "Code": code,
        "Reason": reason,
        "Category": category,
        "Created": created,
        "Username": username,
        "OtherLocation": otherLocation,
        "Room": room,
        "Floor": floor,
        "CodeBlueDone": codeBlueDone,
        "CodeBlueDoneDate": codeBlueDoneDate,
        "LocationCode": locationCode,
        "PatientType": patientType,
        "EmergencyType": emergencyType,
        "FilledDateTime": filledDateTime,
        "SubmitDateTime": submitDateTime,
        "Type": type,
        "CallTime": callTime.toIso8601String(),
        "Status": status,
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `response.body` is in correct **type** and **format**. And try decoding via this code:

```dart
    final List<dynamic> decodedResponseBody = jsonDecode(response.body);
```

resource: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/jsonDecode.html